# Some VMs cannot decrypt what was encrypted from the same AES and password in C#

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, virtual-machine, aes

Hi I have following encryption and decryption codes in C#:

```
    public static string EncryptToBase64(string content, byte[] password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
            return content;

        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        string base64Encoded;

       
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create("AES"))
        {                
            encryptor.KeySize = 256; // 32 * 8 == AES 256
            encryptor.BlockSize = 128; // 16 * 8
            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            encryptor.GenerateIV();

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 100);
            encryptor.Key = key.GetBytes(encryptor.KeySize / 8);
            

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                }
                byte[] bt = ms.ToArray();
                // here we prepend the IV (16 bytes) to the cypher text
                var mixed = encryptor.IV.Concat(bt).ToArray();

                base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(mixed);
            }             
            return base64Encoded;
        }
    }
```

And the Decrypt goes like:

```
    public static string DecryptBase64(string base64content, byte[] password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64content))
            return base64content;

        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create("AES"))
        {
            encryptor.KeySize = 256; // 32 * 8 == AES 256
            encryptor.BlockSize = 128; // 16 * 8
            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            encryptor.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            byte[] encyptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64content);

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 100);
            encryptor.Key = key.GetBytes(encryptor.KeySize / 8);
            encryptor.IV = encyptedBytes.Take(16).ToArray(); // pull first 16 bytes

            string plaintext = string.Empty;

            //int byteCount = 0;
            byte[] cipherBytes = encyptedBytes.Skip(16).ToArray(); // take remaining 
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherBytes.Length];

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            return plaintext.TrimEnd('\0'); // zero padded so chuck out the extra \0 values
        }
    }
```

This works when the service of encryption hosted locally. But when it is in a VM it seems encrypted one cannot be decrypted back. Decryption is working inside an app hosted on Azure.
What could go wrong? is there any impact coming from VMs? I checked all the encrypt passwords and .net versions and they are all same. Any advice or checkpoints would be appreciated.

Comment: You need `new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.UTF8)` but that might not be your only issue.

Comment: @Charlieface will check that too

Comment: The following may be of interest: [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1488).

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid thanks for the link, will inspect on the padding

Comment: *...But when it is in a VM it seems encrypted one cannot be decrypted back...* That statement doesn't really give any information about what went wrong.